# Half oval button in swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, swift5

How can I have Half Oval `UIButton` in Swift.

I want to have a button that has the shape of the grey area of the image

Note: the black background is not part of the button. The button is just the grey one.

[image]

I tried with

```
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath.init(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width / 2, y: bounds.size.height), radius: bounds.size.width / 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: true)
    let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()
    circleShape.path = circlePath.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = circleShape
```

But I am getting semi-circle shape. Also I tried with changing the center and the radius of the arc still no chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems the problem really is merely drawing the shape shown in your drawing. If you can do that, you can use the shape however you like — for example, you can fill it and use the filled shape in a shape layer as a mask, and you already know how to do that. So let's concentrate on just the shape.

I was able to draw your shape like this:

[image]

I think that's a pretty fair approximation to what you've provided. Now I'll tell you how I drew it.

I assume the following relative dimensions (of course you can tweak these as desired): The vertical straight line on the right should be to the horizontal straight parts in the ratio 4:3.

For simplicity, then, I will just use dimensions of 40 (vertical) and 30 (horizontal straight), and I'll make my working space 50 points wide to allow room for the end-cap.

Here we go:

```
    // assume proportions height 40, straight horizontal part 30
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    // start at the top right
    path.move(to: .init(x: 50, y: 0))
    // draw the top line
    path.addLine(to: .init(x: 20, y: 0))
    // add the arc
    path.addRelativeArc(
        center: .init(x: 20, y: 20),
        radius: 20,
        startAngle: -.pi/2,
        delta: -.pi
    )
    // draw the bottom line
    path.addLine(to: .init(x: 50, y: 40))
    // finish
    path.closeSubpath()
```

That's it! If you assign that path to a CAShapeLayer, you'll find that you get the shape in the picture above. Now you can simply adjust the parameters as desired and use the path in whatever way you like.

Comment: can you please explain how to do it so the arc is on the right side? I tried changing -pi/2 to pi/2 but I get a strange shape.

Comment: I don't know what your code for that looks like, but I absolutely know what you mean about the strange shape! One tiny mistake and you can get some pretty weird effects. :) You probably need to reverse the sense of _both_ the `startAngle` _and_ the `delta`. That's because the sense of `delta` (whether it is positive or negative) tells the drawing system whether to travel clockwise or counterclockwise round the arc.